# Why it does not see my file in raw folder

Tags: android

```
    mySoundPoolMap.put(SOUND_01, mySoundPool.load(this, R.raw.effect, 1));
```

I created a raw folder and put it a effect.ogg file but eclipse gives error and says me to create this in R. file. Why?

Comment: Because you're telling Eclipse to search it in the R class.

Comment: whats your `raw` folder's path?

Comment: make sure you're not suing Android.R and instead using yourpackage's R. to do so you need to check the imports in the class that you have. Also rebuilding the project might be useful.